# Test head of expression tree in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

i am new to Sympy and in Python too. I am trying to understand how to test head of expression. For example:

```
expr = sympify("cos(1-x)")
```

how can i understand that head of expr is 'cos'? What code should i write?
And the same question for arbitrary function, for instance:

```
expr = sympify("somefunc(cos(x))")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the root of the expression tree with the `func` attribute. For example:

```
print(expr.func)
# out: cos
```

Or you can use `isinstance`, for example:

```
isinstance(expr, cos)
# out: True
```